# How to position text and Div on top of eachother and align them in center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I can't figure this out. 
I'm trying to get a red vertical box to display in middle of page. I've set the div's margin to auto.
And then there's another div that holds a centered text.
Setting margin auto on both. 
They are both stacking on top of eachother fine in middle of page.

However I want it to be responsive to all heights. Right now it's just responsive to the x-axis and not the height.

HTML & CSS:

```css
.parentDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: auto;
}
#RedBox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin: auto;
}
#CSText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 250px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv" style="margin-top: auto;">
  <div id="CSText" class="TextAlignCenter">
  </div>
  <div id="RedBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your starting `div`-Tag with class attribute.

Comment: How can you make it responsive if your going to use px measuring unit to fix the width and height of the divs. Try using view port size measurement unit (vw for width and vh for height) or the percentage size measurement unit (%) on the width and height of the box. Now for centering take a look at the this w3c style examples on how to center texts,blocks and images on both axis. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flexbox` would be a great solution to this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.red-box {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-box">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/95ssv6q1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div class="inner">
     <div id="RedBox">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentDiv {
     display:table;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
 }
 .inner{
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
 }
 #RedBox {
    width: 250px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: auto;
}
```